# How are release notes updated for staggered roll out in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm confused on how the release notes are published for a staggered release. For example, if I push out an update X with some release notes and later I roll out update Y to 30% of the users. Will the remaining 70% of the users who are yet to receive update Y see the latest release notes?